# Asynchronous texture upload with Qt and OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, asynchronous

I'm writing a small video player using QOpenGLWidget. At the moment I'm struggling to get asynchronous texture upload working. In an earlier version of my code I wait for a "next frame" signal, upon which the frame is read from the hard drive, uploaded to the GPU and then rendered. Now I want to get this working asynchronously using a ring buffer on the GPU. I want a separate thread to upload the next N textures and the main thread to take one of this textures, display and invalidate it. As a first step I wrote a class to upload a single texture which I want to use from my QOpenGLWidget. I created shared contexts between my class and the QOpenGLWidget.

```
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions;

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&m_vao);
    m_program->bind();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

    m_program->setUniformValue("textureSamplerRed", 0);
    m_program->setUniformValue("textureSamplerGreen", 1);
    m_program->setUniformValue("textureSamplerBlue", 2);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_matMVP_Loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_MVP[0][0]);

    m_vertice_indices_Vbo.bind();
    m_vertices_Vbo.bind();
    m_texture_coordinates_Vbo.bind();


    glDrawElements(
        GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,      // mode
        m_videoFrameTriangles_indices.size(),    // count
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,   // type
        (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
    );

    m_program->release();

}
```

I wait for the GLWidget::initializeGL() to finish, emit a signal which is connected to the initialization of my texture loading class:

```
class TextureLoader2 : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions;

void TextureLoader2::initialize(QOpenGLContext *context)
{    
  // sharing the OpenGL context with GLWidget      
  m_context.setFormat(context->format()); // need this?
  m_context.setShareContext(context);  
  m_context.create();

  m_context.makeCurrent(context->surface());
  m_surface = context->surface();    
}
```

And here is how I load a new frame:

```
void TextureLoader2::loadNextFrame(const int frameIdx)
{

    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    bool is_current = m_context.makeCurrent(m_surface);

    // some code which reads the frame from disk and sends to the GPU. 
    // srcR is a pointer to the the data for red. the upload for G and B is similar
    if(!m_texture_Rdata)
    {
        m_texture_Rdata = std::make_shared<QOpenGLTexture>(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
        m_texture_Rdata->create();
        m_texture_Rdata->setSize(m_frameWidth,m_frameHeight);
        m_texture_Rdata->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::R8_UNorm);
        m_texture_Rdata->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::Red,QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
        m_texture_Rdata->setData(QOpenGLTexture::Red, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, srcR);
        // Set filtering modes for texture minification and  magnification
        m_texture_Rdata->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
        m_texture_Rdata->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
        m_texture_Rdata->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToBorder);
    }
    else
    {
        m_texture_Rdata->setData(QOpenGLTexture::Red, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, srcR);
    }

    // these are QOpenGLTextures
    m_texture_Rdata->bind(0);
    m_texture_Gdata->bind(1);
    m_texture_Bdata->bind(2);

    emit frameUploaded();
}
```

My QOpenGLWidget is displaying nothing unfortunately. I don't know how to proceed.
I know that the code for reading and sending the texture to the GPU is working, since if I leave out the line

```
bool is_current = m_context.makeCurrent(m_surface);
```

my whole window (not just the frame containing the QOpenGLWidget) is overwritten, displaying the texture.
I've been searching quite a bit, but I couldn't find any simple working example code for what I want to do. Hope someone has an idea what the issue might be. I've seen people mentioning using QOffscreenSurface or a second hidden widget it similar, but different contexts. Maybe I have to use one of those?

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 fragmentUV;

// Ouput data
out vec4 color_0;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D textureSamplerRed;
uniform sampler2D textureSamplerGreen;
uniform sampler2D textureSamplerBlue;

void main(){    
    vec3 myColor;
    myColor.r = texture2D( textureSamplerRed, fragmentUV ).r;
    myColor.g = texture2D( textureSamplerGreen, fragmentUV ).r;
    myColor.b = texture2D( textureSamplerBlue, fragmentUV ).r;

    color_0 = vec4(, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of these `bind` operations in the upload thread? How do you create the textures, and how do you communicate the texture IDs between the threads?

Comment: I don't have access to the QOpenGLTexture objects in GLWidget::paintGL, that's why I bind them in TextureLoader2::loadNextFrame. I don't want to pass the objects between them. I can try using glBindTexture with QOpenGLFunctions and transmit the texture IDs, if you think that's the problem. I thought since the context is shared it should work like this. Note that so far I haven moved the texture loader to a different thread. I will do that once I get the upload from outside the QOpenGLWidget working.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use different threads or not - what matters is that you use different contexts. And while shared contexts do share objects like textures, they do not share the global state (like texture bindings) and container objects (like VAOs or FBOs). I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but it is really impossible to have one context uploading to the texture and another one using that texture _without_ the functions working with the different contexts knowing the texture name (and, in your case, also binding them in both contexts).